# Include Source JAR (of web application) in lib directory of WAR file

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jar, cobertura

We're using Cobertura to generate test coverage for our deployed web application. It needs to find the source JARs on the classpath of the application in order to produce our HTML reports.

Our Maven build produces:

```
target/our-webapp-sources.jar (about 40k)
target/our-webapp.war (about 20MB)
```

And when deployed in Tomcat, we have (under `WEB-INF`)

```
classes/... (the .class files) ...
lib/our-service-library.jar
lib/our-service-library-sources.jar
lib/our-core-library.jar
lib/our-core-library-sources.jar
```

So we are able to instrument, but only display the source files for our profiled `Service` and `Core` projects. What we *want* is for our `-sources` JAR for the webapp itself to be deployed *as a dependency* under the `lib` directory. So we want:

```
classes/... (the .class files) ...
lib/our-webapp-sources.jar
lib/our-service-library.jar
lib/our-service-library-sources.jar
...
```

We can manually specify (to the Cobertura command-line script) a directory to look for source files (thinking we could just give it the sources JAR separately), but doing so **overrides** the other sources. So we can get the web service sources included, but when we do so, we lose the source files for the `Core` and `Service`.

We're using Maven profiles - so this will only be an instrumentation-specific deployment, but we would like to tweak the `maven-war-plugin` or similar to include the `-sources` JAR in the `lib` folder, of the webapp itself.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to configure your `war` project descriptor to include the ***sources*** jar of your web application, it can be simply made as follows:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- other components configuration -->

  <build>
    <finalName>war-with-sources</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>package-and-attach-sources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>${project.build.finalName}-sources.jar</include>
              </includes>
              <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The relevant part here is the `<webResources>` element which instructs maven to include additional resources into your archive determined by:

- `directory` including the archive to add, which should be your build directory since the build `*-sources.jar` file will go there.
- `includes` element that specifies artifacts to include i.e. the sources jar assuming here that it won't be nothing but your web archive name appended with *sources* suffix (default name pattern).
- `targePath` that defines the target inside the `war` archive where configured includes will be copied.

To have you sources jar file copied using the aforementioned configuration, you have to tell maven to generate project sources which is not done by default.

This can be seamlessly done using the ***maven-sources-plugin*** using a necessary trick by mentioning a maven `<phase>` (in which sources will be generated) that **must** come before the **package** phase (default phase for the maven-war-plugin) e.g. the ***prepare-package*** phase, otherwise you won't get those sources included in your war file. Here down the additional *maven-sources-plugin* configuration that should be appended to the above *pom.xml* descriptor:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <build>
    <finalName>war-with-sources</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <!-- other plugins configuration -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

[Here](https://github.com/tmarwen/stackoverflow-showcase/blob/master/war-with-sources/pom.xml) you can find a working sample from which you can copy/use the project descriptor configuration.